# Assimp's aiImportFile() identifier not found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opengl, assimp

Here I have my headers:

```
// ASSIMP
#include <assimp\Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp\scene.h>
#include <assimp\postprocess.h>
```

It compiles and there's no unresolved externals so my library file should be correct.

But further down:

```
/* load file with assimp and print some stats */

const aiScene* scene = aiImportFile(file_name, aiProcess_Triangulate);
if (!scene) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: reading mesh %s\n", file_name);
    return false;
}
```

I get an error with aiImportFile that its identifier isn't found. Which is baffling as pretty much everything else from assimp works.

How do I fix this? At the moment compiling the source code of assimp doesn't work, I don't get any library files so I'm stuck with whats available under "full".

Comment: I'm gettting the same error.If I'l find a solution  I will post it here.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm pretty sure I solved this a while back and forgot I had this up, the solution is likely to run it in Release mode, are you running the code in Debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much work on finding a solution, I'm pretty sure the problem was compiling the library in debug mode. I believe it only works in Release mode.

Unfortunately this was a while back and don't have the code currently on my computer so I'm not 100% sure, but I am 90% sure.

Comment: To confirm I also had this problem when building in Debug mode. Release mode worked fine.